# Calling COM object of an application that are installed in host machine from docker Windows container

Tags: .net, docker, com, windows-container

I have a dotnet core application, for simplicity, it's a console app.
I also have a application installed on the host machine, Adobe Illustrator.
The simplest code run on the console is something like this:

```cs
var app = new Illustrator.Application();
app.Open(@"C:\temp\foo.ai");
```

After adding COM reference to the project, when executing it, it will open the Illustrator application, and open the specified file.

Now, my question, is possible for me to run that console app in Windows Container, and still able to perform the task as above?

Thank you!!